# How do I reconcile these two verses?

Tags: contradiction, god

During the Sermon on the Mount, Jesus blessed the poor and promised that they shall inherit the earth. He also blessed the **pure in heart** and promised them that they shall **see God**.

Mathew 5:8

> Blessed are the pure in heart, for they will see God.

However, Paul in an epistle to Timothy said that no one has **ever seen or can see God**.

1 Timothy 6:16

> who only hath immortality, dwelling in the light which no man can approach unto, whom no man hath seen nor can see, to whom be honor and power everlasting. Amen.

Was Jesus referring to himself when he promised the pure in heart shall see God (in terms of holes in hands and feet)? This is because Paul eliminated the possibility of seeing the Father with **or can see God** which will also include the angels and other heavenly beings that already live close to the Great White Throne.

Comment: No _man_ hath seen God. No _man_ can approach unto Him. But the pure in heart, who approach God in Christ (that is to say _in another humanity_ ) they see God. Theirs is the kingdom of heaven. Up-voted +1. I was thinking of these very two verses whilst taking a walk yesterday. I hope to prepare a more full answer when time permits me to do so.

Comment: @NigelJ, there is a lot of truth hidden in that parable. I know it's not possible to see God and live.

Comment: Not possible for the created creature - no. But those born of water and of spirit do so.

Comment: @NigelJ,I get you now. _Man_ cant but the _saints_ will.

Comment: Yes, indeed. _Yet a little while, and the world seeth me no more; **but ye see me**: because I live, ye shall live also._ John 14:19. It is present tense, not future. It is now.

Comment: @NigelJ The nearer we come to seeing that people _saw_ Jesus whereas no one has ever seen _God_, the closer pressed are those who want to believe that Jesus was God.  In John 14:19, the Greek word used is "θεωρεῖτέ" (G2334).  That's a different one than any of the verbs addressed in the question or in the accepted answer with respect to seeing God, but looks to be a derivative of the G2300 used in 1 John 4:12 that applies specifically to the sense of sight and which John uses to definitively state no one has seen God at any time.

Comment: @Biblasia _After_ Jesus says 'the world seeth (θεωρει) me no more, he then says 'but ye see me' (θεωρειτε). The context is _after_.

Comment: @NigelJ Having been seen even once, it matters not when, whether _before_ or _after_, would contradict the texts which say no one has seen God _at any time_.  Jesus was seen.  Everyone knows that.  Multiple Greek words are used to say so.  The logical conclusion is so simple and obvious that a grade-school student could reach it...easily.

Comment: @Biblasia I agree fully with your last sentence.  No _man_ has seen God at any time. But ye (sons of God) see me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Blessed are the poor in spirit: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.
> (Matthew 5:3, KJV)
>
> Blessed are the pure in heart: for they shall see God. (Matthew 5:8,
> KJV)

Jesus addresses each listener of these words in a manner consistent with understanding their needs.  Each one will look to find his or her own place among the blessings, and consider how they will be personally applied.  When one sees "poor in spirit," one may take it to mean downhearted, discouraged, or sad; but Jesus means it to apply to those who see themselves as spiritually weak.

Like the publican, who dared not even lift his eyes toward heaven in prayer, but thought of himself as unworthy, those who are poor in spirit are humble.  Their humility commends them to God.  It shows that in reality they are more pure in heart than those who exalt themselves and feel they are righteous.

These "pure in heart" are the ones who will come nearest to understanding God and having an experience with Him.  And that is what the expression "they shall see God" intends.

In Greek, the word "ὀπτάνομαι/optanomai" (Strong's G3700) is used to mean "to look at, behold."  Had it been translated as "behold" in this verse, its corollation to 2 Corinthians 3:18 would be more clear, for it says: "But we all, with open face **beholding** as in a glass the glory of the Lord, are changed into the same image from glory to glory, even as by the Spirit of the Lord."

Those who see themselves as "poor" are those who seek help from God--who will lift up their eyes on high to behold the Source of their help, and to become more like Him.

The meaning of the Greek text is not limited to the sight of the eyes.  It can apply to the perception of the mind; to one's *experience.*

Here are a few examples of usage of this same Greek word in other texts where it does not apply to the sense of sight.

> And all flesh **shall see<sup>G3700</sup>** the salvation of God. (Luke 3:6,
> KJV)
>
> Saying, I have sinned in that I have betrayed the innocent blood. And
> they said, What is that to us? **see<sup>G3700</sup>** thou to that. (Matthew
> 27:4, KJV)
>
> When Pilate saw that he could prevail nothing, but that rather a
> tumult was made, he took water, and washed his hands before the
> multitude, saying, I am innocent of the blood of this just person:
> **see<sup>G3700</sup>** ye to it. (Matthew 27:24, KJV)
>
> He that believeth on the Son hath everlasting life: and he that
> believeth not the Son **shall<sup>G3700</sup>** not **see<sup>G3700</sup>** life; but the
> wrath of God abideth on him. (John 3:36, KJV)

The text also refers clearly to the future, saying they *will* see God.  This can be fulfilled at any future time, inclusive of some point in time after Christ has come and/or this present world has come to its end.  Nothing in the text requires that anyone now living should have seen God; thus, there is no contradiction to other passages that plainly teach no man has seen God at any time.

Notably, none of the major texts declaring that no one has ever seen God uses the same Greek word as Jesus used in his blessings.

> No man **hath seen<sup>G3708</sup>** God at any time, the only
> begotten Son, which is in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared
> him. (John 1:18, KJV)
>
> No man **hath seen<sup>G2300</sup>** God at any time. If we love one
> another, God dwelleth in us, and his love is perfected in us. (1 John
> 4:12, KJV)
>
> Who only hath immortality, dwelling in the light which no man can
> approach unto; whom no man **hath seen<sup>G1492</sup>**, nor can see:
> to whom be honour and power everlasting. Amen. (1 Timothy 6:16, KJV)

Of special interest is that verb that John uses in 1 John 4:12, because that one (G2300) is always used for the actual sense of sight, and is nowhere in the New Testament used for symbolic, euphemistic, nor allegorical purpose.  In today's vernacular, perhaps one might say that no one has "laid eyes" on God; but even in English, "to see" can have many uses, and can apply to more than one's physical eyesight.

### Conclusion

There is no contradiction between Jesus' blessing and the passages that declare no has has ever seen God.  First, none of those passages says that no one *will ever* see God, as Jesus' words seem to indicate; and secondly, the Greek word translated as "see" can have more meanings than to literally "see" with one's eyes, and it is a different Greek word than is used to say no one has seen God.

Comment: Perhaps we could add 1 Corinthians ch13 v12 to the hints about "future" seeing of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that Jesus's blessings are in the future tense.
These good people *will* inherit the Earth, but not just yet.

John described this in the Book of Revelation.
Those people that have accepted God's salvation during this age (the "elect") will be resurrected (as immortal spirits) at Christ's return.
They will rule the Kingdom of God with Christ during the Millennium, here on Earth.

> And I saw thrones, and they sat upon them, and judgment was given unto them: and I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded for their testimony about Jesus and for proclaiming the word of God.
> They had not worshiped the beast or his statue, nor accepted his mark on their forehead or their hands.
> They all came to life again, and they reigned with Christ for a thousand years.
> This is the first resurrection.
>
> (The rest of the dead did not come back to life until the thousand years had ended.)
>
> Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection.
> For them the second death holds no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with him a thousand years.
> — Revelation 20:4–6  (NLT)

At the end of the Millennium those people that were never offered God's salvation (the vast majority of mankind) will be resurrected (as mortal physical bodies).
They will then be taught about God's way, and most will accept his offer of salvation.

> The sea gave up its dead, and death and the grave gave up their dead. And all were judged according to their deeds.
> — Revelation 20:13

Only a relatively few individuals will refuse God's salvation (the "unpardonable sin"), and they will mercifully be permanently destroyed:

> And anyone whose name was not found recorded in the Book of Life was thrown into the lake of fire.
> — Revelation 20:15

By then, all of mankind will now have become immortal spirits.
Sin, death, and the grave now become meaningless terms:

> Then death and the grave were thrown into the lake of fire. This lake of fire is the second death.
> — Revelation 20:14

Finally, God the Father (whom no man has ever seen) will descend from his Heaven to greet his children:

> And I saw the holy city, the new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven like a bride beautifully dressed for her husband.
> I heard a loud shout from the throne, saying, “Look, God’s home is now among his people! He will live with them, and they will be his people. God himself will be with them.
> — Revelation 21:2–3

Comment: _"Only a relatively few individuals will refuse God's salvation..."_  That is not correct, and Jesus told us the exact opposite.  "Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is the gate, and broad is the way, that leadeth to destruction, and many there be which go in thereat: Because strait is the gate, and **narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find it."** (Matthew 7:13-14, KJV)

Comment: @Biblasia, Jesus was talking about the elect, the small number of people that are called to salvation during this current age. I was taking about the billions of people in the second resurrection, who will be living in the Kingdom and personally instructed in God's ways. Almost all of them will accept God's holy spirit and receive salvation. 1 Timothy 2:4 says that God "*wants everyone to be saved and to understand the truth*".

Comment: Unless you're calling the resurrection that occurs at Christ's "second advent" the "second resurrection" (most would call it the _first_), it would appear that you would be correct about the numbers of people being resurrected, but incorrect as to what their fate is--for that resurrection that occurs following the millennium in Heaven is that in which the lost are raised to face their judgment.  None will then have opportunity to switch sides.  Their destiny has been determined.  There is no second chance, as many dangerously believe.

Comment: _will be resurrected (as immortal spirits)_ This is not true as God alone has immortality, read 1 Timothy 6:16

Comment: @DongLi, Timothy's statement was certainly true when he said it. But probably the most famous verse in the Bible is John 3:16, which talks about humanity *after* their resurrection: "*For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that **whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life**.*".  As someone said in a comment on the question: "I get you now. *Man* can't but the *saints* will.

Comment: @Biblasia.  It's the the *first* general resurrection that occurs at Christ's "second advent". Then the Millennium. Then the *second* general resurrection.  Then the judgement. The people in the second resurrection never had a "first chance" (e.g. someone that died in central China in 1000 BC), so for them this is not a *second chance*.

Comment: everlasting life is not the same as immortality.

Comment: @DongLi says "*everlasting life is not the same as immortality*".  Huh? My dictionary says that "immortality" means "*the ability to live forever; eternal life*". So you are saying that "everlasting" is not the same as "eternal"?

Comment: Ray, I actually agree with Dong Li on the terminology.  Only God has true immortality.  Immortality is something inherent--it is _impossible_ for God to die; whereas the eternal life of those whom God has created is granted conditionally upon their obedience to Him.  Lucifer and his fallen angel host is a good example:  For thousands of years they have lived--but they have never been "immortal," and their end is coming.  Had they remained loyal to God, they would have lived forever.

Comment: Regarding the second resurrection, the Bible calls it the resurrection of damnation.  "And shall come forth; they that have done good, unto the resurrection of life; and they that have done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation." (John 5:29, KJV)  Those are the two resurrections.  Jesus does not teach a second chance theory; those who are not resurrected with all of the saints at Jesus' coming will not be among those who receive eternal life.

Comment: @Biblasia says "*Immortality is something inherent*". Yet in 1 Corinthians 15:53,54, those individuals in the first resurrection "*put on immortality*". They have just been reborn as immortal children of God.

Comment: @RayButterworth While it is true that the saints will live forever after the resurrection, it is of interest that this will be conditional upon their continuance in eating of the Tree of Life.  It is the Tree's fruit that will continuously prolong the lives of the saints.  While no one will cease eating of this fruit--in theory, if one chose to do so, he might not live forever.  But "putting on immortality" is not exactly the same as _being_ immortal, either.  Perhaps it is a figure of speech referencing the adoption of God's character, also portrayed by the washed, white robes in Revelation.

Comment: @Biblasia quotes John, "*they that have done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation*", which is a strong translation. Other versions say "*resurrection of judgement*". which is not the same as "Damnation". The Greek word translated as "*evil*" means "*easy, slight, ordinary, mean, worthless, of no account; ethically, bad, wicked, base*". The "*resurrection of life*" is the first resurrection, where saints are reborn as spirits; the "*resurrection of judgement*" is the second resurrection, where people will be taught God's way and then judged, in their *first* and only chance of salvation.

Comment: @Biblasia says "*While it is true that the saints will live forever after the resurrection, it is of interest that this will be conditional upon their continuance in eating of the Tree of Life.*". I've never heard of any Christian denomination that claims that following the final resurrection and the end of death, the children of God, who have been been converted to spirit beings and given eternal life, can still lose their salvation. That statement is worthy of a being a question in Christianity.SE.

Comment: @RayButterworth It's not a matter of _salvation_--they are already saved, and of course no one will lose their salvation at that point; it's a matter of the source of their _longevity_.

Comment: @Biblasia, yes it will be as long as they don't rebel as the devil and his angels lived for thousands of years but when they rebeled they lost their former places. God is showing the saints that life everlasting remains on the condition that they remain loyal and obedient to Him.

Comment: Everlasting life is as a result of perpetual access to the tree of life but immortality is a property of God that sets him apart from his creation.